# Change JSON content field type using Node.js

Tags: node.js, json, web-crawler

I have crawled some contents from websites using a third party crawling tool and i got a `.json` file successfully after the crawl. My `json`content looks as shown below:

```
  {
   "name": "Mi Band 3 (Black)",
   "price": "₹ 1,899.00",
   "rating_count": "22,438",
   "MRP": "₹ 2,199.00",
   "saved_amount": "₹ 300.00 (14%)"
  }
```

There are plenty of such products crawled, you can see the `price`, `MRP` and `rating_count` are of `String` type here, I want to change it and make number type, also i want to iterate through the `price`,`rating_count`, & `MRP` fields to remove the unwanted characters. I think i can do it using `Node.js`, but i am a newbie in scripting language including `Node.js`, i have read the contents from `.json` file using the below code after checked few `Node.js` basics, and worked it

```
var fs = require('fs');

 fs.readFile('run_results.json','utf8', function (err, data) {
     if (err) throw err;
     console.log('Data here =>', data);
 });
```

But i can't find any particular solution for my case when i have searched, Kindly give some hints to achieve my task, Thank you.

Comment: Actually once you get things in data it is just string manipulation just treat is as string and play along.

Comment: First you need to turn the JSON into an object: `const obj = JSON.parse(data);`. Now you can change its contents: `obj.rating_count = parseInt(obj.rating_count)`

Comment: You can't use `parseInt` on `"₹ 1,899.00"`, `parseInt("₹ 1,899.00")` is `NaN`. Remove all non-digits except decimal point from string firstly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a transformation function as an argument to [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse#Parameters) to convert numeric strings to Numbers:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var numericKeys = ["price", "rating_count", "MRP"];

fs.readFile('run_results.json','utf8', function (err, data) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var results = JSON.parse(data, function(key, value) {
    return (numericKeys.indexOf(key) !== -1)
      ? parseFloat(value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, ''))
      : value;
  });

  console.log(results);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have an array of objects

```
const extractNumber = value => parseFloat(value.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '')); // replace all symbols except number and decimal point, then parse it to int

const items = JSON.parse(data);

const result = items.map(item => ({
  ...item,
  price: extractNumber(item.price),
  rating_count: extractNumber(item.rating_count),
  MRP: extractNumber(item.MRP)
}));
```

Comment: It's an object; objects don't have `.map()`

Comment: If its an object, just apply map callback to it

Comment: You don't understand. Your code creates an Error: `items.map is not a function` Only arrays have a `.map()` method, but `data` is an *Object*.

Comment: My code is not runnable, it's example how to map collection of objects described in question